Why does my LSTM only print out one day?
I made an LSTM for predicting stocks and it only predicts 1 day but I want to predict a range.
def make_new_model(self): 
    # simple starting model
    # builds the lstm model
    ########################

        neural_network = keras.Sequential()
        neural_network.add(layers.LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (self.days_to_train_on, 5))) 
        neural_network.add(layers.LSTM(units = 50))
        neural_network.add(layers.Dense(units = 1))
        neural_network.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
        neural_network.summary()
        return neural_network


My input shape is (2500, 10, 5). I want my output to be (2500, 1, 14)
Eg: take 5 columns of data from past 10 days (2500 total of these samples)
and output a prediction for 1 column over the next 14 days (flattened 1d array of 14 values) x (2500 of these predictions)
what parameters or input shapes should my input data / model have to achieve this goal?
right now, it seems the model predicts 2500 x 1 x 1. How can I make it predict 14 values?
